# Unit testing of webforms with windows autentication

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have created the following test method, when I test it for normal websites it passes, when use an intranet website with windows authentication it fails
and gives `401 Unauthorized` error, how can I test for windows authentication with username and password.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckforPageLoad()
{
    HttpStatusCode result = default(HttpStatusCode);
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://google.ie");
    //var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://webapps.tcd.ie/PortalFramework/Apps/TravelInsurance/Forms/SubmitInsurance");
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            result = response.StatusCode;
            response.Close();
        }
    }
    Assert.AreEqual("OK", result.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add credentials to the request. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx for details.

You can also use the current users credentials by setting UseDefaultCredentials to true if you want to get around storing a password. If running tests on a build server make sure the build account has access to the server.